# Pass component reactive value to parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have this component with a slider, I have a submit button outside this component, can I somehow pass this timeAnswer value to a parent component, so I can submit the data?

```js
div(v-if="timeConstraint")
 VueSlider(
    v-model="timeAnswer.duration",
    v-bind="sliderOptionsEnd()"
  )
```

```js
    const timeAnswer = reactive({ start: 0, duration: 900 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a computed property with getter/setter:

```html
  <vue-slider v-model="sliderValue" />
```

```js
export default
{
  props:
  {
    modelValue:
    {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    }
  },
  computed:
  {
    sliderValue:
    {
      get()
      {
        return this.modelValue
      },
      set(val)
      {
        this.$emit('update:modelValue', val)
      }
    }
  }
}
```